# How can I use get_or_create in TranslatableModel?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-parler

I am using dajngo-parler to make my site multi-language. But I have a problem when querying. For example, in this query, only ID is created and the rest of the fields are not stored in the database.

```py
MyModel.objects.language('en').get_or_create(title='test',description='test')
```

But when I use this method, there is no problem.

```py
MyModel.objects.language('en').create(title='test',description='test')
```

Is there another way to create data in multi-language models with parler??

Comment: What if you use `MyModel.objects.language('en').get_or_create(title='test',description='test', defaults={'_current_language': 'en'})`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem gives an error: ```FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'description' into field. Choices are: created_at, id, translations, updated_at```
than I try this:
```MyModel.objects.language('en').get_or_create(translations__title='test',translations__description='test', defaults={'_current_language': 'en'})```
But it didn't work again.
```FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model MyModel: '_current_language'.```